# what's the extremum of this expression?

Tags: calculus

$$\sin x + \frac 13 \sin 3x, \quad x\in (0,\; \pi)$$

what is the extremum of this expression? Please give me an explanation in detail. Thanks.

Comment: It will help a good deal if you use the trig identity  $ \ \sin 3x = -4 \sin^3 x + 3 \sin x \ . $

Comment: This is not a homework answering service. Pleae motivate your questions, tell us why you have them and what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

What is the derivative of that expression? How can that help you find extrema?